# Will flink resume from the last offset after executing yarn application kill and running again?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, checkpoint

I use FlinkKafkaConsumer to consume kafka and enable checkpoint. Now I'm a little confused on the offset management and checkpoint mechanism.
I have already know flink will start reading partitions from the consumer group’s.
`https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-start-position-configuration` 
and the offset will store into checkpoint in remote fileSystem.
`https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-and-fault-tolerance`

What happen if I stop the application by executing the `yarn application -kill appid`
and run the start command like `./bin flink run ...`?
Will flink get the offset from checkpoint or from group-id managed by kafka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the job again without defining a savepoint (`$ bin/flink run -s :savepointPath [:runArgs]`) flink will try to get the offsets of your consumer-group from kafka (in older versions from zookeeper). But you will loose all other state of your flink job (which might be ignorable if you have a stateless flink job).

I must admit that this behaviour is quite confusing. By default starting a job without a savepoint is like starting from zero. As far as I know only the implementation of the kafka source differs from that behaviour. If you wanna change that behaviour you can set the `setStartFromGroupOffsets` of the `FlinkKafkaConsumer[08/09/10]` to `false`. This is described here: [Kafka Consumers Start Position Configuration](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-start-position-configuration)

It might be worth having a closer look at the documentation of flink: [What is a savepoint and how does it differ from checkpoints](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/savepoints.html#what-is-a-savepoint-how-is-a-savepoint-different-from-a-checkpoint).

In a nutshell

Checkpoints:

> The primary purpose of Checkpoints is to provide a recovery mechanism in case of unexpected job failures. A Checkpoint’s lifecycle is managed by Flink

Savepoints:

> Savepoints are created, owned, and deleted by the user. Their use-case is for planned, manual backup and resume

There are currently ongoing discussions on how to "unify" savepoints and checkpoints. Find a lot of technical details here: [Flink improvals 47: Checkpoints vs Savepoints](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-47%3A+Checkpoints+vs.+Savepoints)

Comment: Got it! Thanks! So Great!